# Scala 3 enum error after conversion from Scala 2

Tags: scala, enums, sbt, scala-3

I converted an old project from Scala 2 to Scala 3, but I can't seem to use `enum`s. For instance, if I create an empty file with just

```scala
enum Color:
  case Red, Green, Blue
```

I get the following error

```
[error] -- [E103] Syntax Error: .../eehh.scala:3:0 
[error] 3 |enum Color:
[error]   |^^^^
[error]   |Illegal start of toplevel definition
...
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 10 s, completed Jun 8, 2022, 2:41:47 PM
[IJ]scalaVersion
[info] 3.1.2
```

Even weirder is that `enum`s seem to work fine in a fresh project.  I have tried restarting the project, and even recloning a fresh version.

The sbt file is here: https://github.com/marklemay/calculus-of-constructions/blob/master/build.sbt .

I can't seem to find references to `[E103]` anywhere.

Comment: Can you share the whole content of the file, or more precisely: what is defined before the enum?

Comment: that is the entire file.  Though I have tried versions that have package declarations, next to object definitions and inside objects.

Comment: I would have said that maybe a `package xx` is necessary for top-level definition but apparently not then.

Comment: yeah I tried that in my working project just to make double sure

Comment: I can't reproduce the error using the provided `build.sbt` file. I would recommend you to run this command in your **sbt** shell `clean;reload;compile` - PS: I see you are using the migrate plugin, I would think the problem is related to that.

Comment: I think you're right, the conversion plugin is doing something weird, like forcing support for Scala 2.  It works when I disable the plugin and reload.  I can re-break things by re-adding the plugin. Though it is strange this isn't consistent across systems.

Comment: If you make an answer gesturing at this I would accept it.  If we could more reliably trigger the behavior I'd file a bug report.